# Same partitioning: for a data frame and later for an RDD of this data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, partitioning

I use multiple window functions with the spec on a dataframe df:

```
windowSpec = \
  Window 
    .partitionBy(df['customID'])
```

Later i use:

```
df.rdd.map((x[0],x[0], x[1], x[2]))

and df.mapPartitions(some func)
```

to create kv-pairs of my dataframe and work on paritions on RDDs. Since

```
x[0] = df.['customID']
```

in my case, i wonder how  can i work/Keep the paritioning that was already used by the window spec. Is this the most efficient way to work on paritions with RDDs after working with dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Transforming `DataFrame` to `RDD` doesn't require shuffle so content of the partitions will be the same for both objects. However, `Partitioner` won't be preserved.

This should be still enough for your use case, although vectroized udf might be a better choice than `RDD`.

Comment: What's _"vectroized udf"_?